# How to create below parallelograms with responsive using css shapes

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am working on a website where I have to create something similar, what is showing in the image below.And it should be in responsive.[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osQQA.png)

Any one can help me on this.

Regards,

Raj kumar

Comment: there are multiple ways. you can use either css skew transforms or use clip path to "cut" a rectangle into a parallelogram

Answer (score 0):

You should use `transform: skew()`:

```css
.paralelogram {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
.paralelogram p {
    transform: skewX(30deg);
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="paralelogram"><p>lorem ipsum</p><div>
```